# Implication of period of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions

Let $f:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function with nonconstant derivative $f'$ on $(0,1)$. Is it possible that there exists a real number $t$ such that $f'(x)=f'(x+t)$ for all $x$ such that $x,x+t\in(0,1)$, but $f(x)\neq f(x+t)$ for some $x$ such that $x,x+t\in(0,1)$?

If the question were the other way round (i.e., $f(x)=f(x+t)$ for all $x$ but $f'(x)=f'(x+t)$ for some $x$), but it is not possible by definition of derivative. But for the direction in question, it's much less clear. Also, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413830/period-of-derivative-is-the-period-of-the-original-function) is different because it assumes that $f$ is periodic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f(x) = 40\pi x+\cos(20\pi x)$. Its derivative $f^\prime$ is periodic with period $1/10$, yet $f$ is injective (it is strictly increasing).

Comment: More generally, by writing for some $x_0\in(0,1)$ such that $x_0+t\in(0,1)$ that
$$
f(x) - f(x_0) = \int_{x_0}^x f^\prime(u)du = \int_{x_0}^x f^\prime(u+t)du
= \int_{x_0+t}^{x+t} f^\prime(u)du = f(x+t)-f(x_0+t)
$$
you get
$$
f(x+t) = f(x) + \left(f(x_0+t) - f(x_0)\right)
$$
and the last term has to be zero for the function to be $t$-periodic.